# improve fast enumeration performance

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, nsarray, fast-enumeration

I have a huge word list of over 280.000+ words that is loaded from an sqlite database to an NSArray.  then I do a fast enumeration to check if a certain string value entered by the user matches one of the words in the Array. Since the array is so large it takes about 1-2 seconds on the iphone 4 to go through that array.

How can I improve the performance? Maybe I should make several smaller arrays? one for each letter in the alphabet so that there is less data to go through.

this is how my database class looks

```
static WordDatabase *_database;

+(WordDatabase *) database
{

    if (_database == nil) {

        _database = [[WordDatabase alloc] init];

    }

    return _database;
}

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dictionary" ofType:@"sqlite"];


        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
    }
    return self;

}

- (NSArray *)dictionaryWords {

    NSMutableArray *retval = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString *query = @"SELECT word FROM words";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            char *wordChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);

            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:wordChars];

            name = [name uppercaseString];

            [retval addObject:name];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    return retval;

}
```

then in my main view I initialise it like this

```
dictionary = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[WordDatabase database].dictionaryWords];
```

and finally I go through the array using this method

```
- (void) checkWord
{    
    NSString *userWord = formedWord.wordLabel.string;
    NSLog(@"checking dictionary for %@", userWord);

    for (NSString *word in dictionary) {
        if ([userWord isEqualToString: word]) {   
        NSLog(@"match found");    
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace NSArray with NSSet, then checkWord becomes [set containsObject:word].

Comment: indeed. changing the NSArray to a NSSet has made the checking almost instantly. although the initial loading of the dictionary has become slightly longer. but that's a small tradeoff.

Comment: That's still a lot of memory though.  If your app needs to do other stuff, you may well find that the SQL search is good enough, especially if you index your database on the words...  You could even just use the SQL database as a large has table.  Create a hash with the word, then ask the database for all words matching that hash.  A linear search on that small list will be nothing, and SQL search on an indexed integer value is very fast.  Then you don't have to use all that memory either.

Comment: Any sample code on how to do a sqlite search in ios? This is my first time using sqlite so I don't really know the syntax to achieve this.

Comment: You are already doing it.  Give it a SELECT statement.  However, if you use a hash as a key you would do something like: "SELECT word FROM words WHERE hashkey = 12345" where you substitute 12345 with the hash key you create from the word.  In this case, the database would return all the rows that match that hash key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of different ways.

- stick all the words in a dictionary or set, testing for presence is fast
- break it up as you suggest; create a tree type structure of some kind.
- use the database to do the search.  They are generally pretty good at exactly that, if constructed correctly.

Comment: You'd want a set, not a dictionary, since the data does not appear to be keyed.

Comment: True enough;  a set will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If space isn't an issue, store a hash value of each word and use that for your base lookup. Once filtered by the hash, then compare each of the words.  This will reduce the number of costly string comparisons.  Easier to index/sort and performs quick lookups.

Answer (score 0):

I second a dictionary. NSDictionary for objective c.

for instance:

// To print out all key-value pairs in the NSDictionary myDict

```
 for(id key in myDict)
    NSLog(@"key=%@ value=%@", key, [myDict objectForKey:key]);
```

Comment: Note that block based enumeration of dictionaries is significantly faster in that it doesn't require a hash lookup to get the value.